# Can you achieve a moment?

Tags: meaning

I'm writing an essay, and I'd like to write a phrase like "He finally achieved the moment he'd been working towards his whole life."

Is it okay to say that someone "achieved" a moment?

Comment: Sure it's not literal, but if you can work towards a moment, then you could achieve it too.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a little weird to me.  One works toward an achievement and there can be a moment in time when that achievement is realized, but it’s the achievement one works  toward, not the moment: *And in that moment he’d finally realized the achievement he’d been working towards his whole life.*

Answer (score 3):

You can reach a moment you work toward.

But I would say you achieve an accomplishment not a point in time.

Answer (score 2):

*Achieved* is perfectly fine.

As an alternative, how about *realized*?

> He finally *realized* the moment he'd been working towards his entire
>   life.

From M-W:

> [*realize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realize): to
>   achieve (something, such as a goal, dream, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to achieve a *dream* or a *goal*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rest of the essay is about but I think a good sentence would be:
He finally reached the moment he had been working towards all his life, the achievement of his goal. (which, if you leave out the rest, says: he finally reached his goal)or:
The moment he had been working towards all his life, the achievement of his goal,finally arrived.